# CGAffineTransform animation in cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I'm having an issue with animating an `UIImageView` inside an `CollectionViewCell`. I've set the views with `Auto Layout`, not sure if that could cause a problem.

If tried calling in `didEndDisplaying` but with no results.
What is the proper lifecycle function to call an cell animation?

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ProfileCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    ....

    let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "lustrum2017")
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    var blurView: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let be = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let vv = UIVisualEffectView(effect: be)
        return vv
    }()

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "dummy")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        iv.layer.borderColor = Colors.primaryColor.cgColor
        iv.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        iv.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
        animateViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func animateViews() {

        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45, animations: { 
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(blurView)

        contentView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: backgroundImageView)
        contentView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(150)]", views: backgroundImageView)

        contentView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: blurView)
        contentView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(150)]", views: blurView)

        blurView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        blurView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-\(frame.width / 2 - 40)-[v0(80)]-\(frame.width / 2 - 40)-|", views: profileImageView)
        blurView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(80)]", views: profileImageView)
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: If you need to animate something? Firstly you'll need to setting up an initial value, and then you can animate to your desired value. For example: set transform value to 0.75 and then 1.0; something like that.

Comment: As you can see I've allready did that when constructing the imageview.

Comment: It's a custom class for the UICollectionViewCell. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing the transformation inside of the `UIView.animate` block and it should work. As follows:

```
private func animateViews() {

    self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45, animations: { 
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Also, if you created the cell from the storyboard/xib instead of manually registering the cell via code, `awakeFromNib` might get you the result you want.

Edit: The above answer is assuming that you want the animation to occur once the cell is first created, as it seems more similar to the code you have. If you want to have it be called every time the cell appears on screen then you need to use the `UICollectionViewDelegate`'s `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`

Comment: This is not working for me, even when calling in the animation in `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`.

Comment: Did you make sure to apply the transform inside the UIView.animation block? It won't animate without it, having `self.layoutIfNeeded` inside will only animate any constraint-based animations